# Passing a vector to rbg in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to pass a vector to the `rgb` function in R (version 3.1.2).  According to the documentation for `rgb`,

> The colors may be specified by passing a matrix or data frame as argument red, and leaving blue and green missing. In this case the first three columns of red are taken to be the red, green and blue values.

But when I actually try to do this, I get an error:

```
rgb(c(0, 0, 0))
# Error in rgb(c(0, 0, 0)) : argument "green" is missing, with no default
```

By contrast, this works fine:

```
rgb(0, 0, 0)
# [1] "#000000"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe try `do.call(rgb, list(0, 0, 0))`?

Comment: What would that accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as soon as I posted this, I figured out the answer.  The object has to actually be a matrix or a data.frame.  So this works correctly:

```
 rgb(matrix(c(0, 0, 0), ncol = 3))
 # [1] "#000000"
```

Whoops.  Hopefully this helps someone else, though.

Answer (score 0):

`rgb` expects a matrix or dataframe, not a vector. It returns a vector of colors, one for each row in the matrix or data frame. So this two-row matrix:

```
matrix(1:6,2,3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  0.1  0.1  0.1
#[2,]  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

will produce  a vector of 2 colors

```
rgb(matrix(0.1:0.9,2,3))
#[1] "#1A1A1A" "#1A1A1A"
```