# Edit RGB colors of Cells in Data Table (R)

Tags: r, datatable, colors, rgb, dt

I am working on a project that includes a data table.  I would like the data table cells to be colored by similar values in a column. I am struggling to understand how to modify the code below to be able to choose colors in my data table.  The code was taken from another example I found on Stackoverflow:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- cbind.data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE))
brks <- apply(df, 2, quantile, probs=seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm=T)
clrs <- apply( brks, 2, function(x) round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(x)+1), 0) 
%>% {paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")})
eval(parse(text=paste0("datatable(df) ", paste(sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) 
paste0("%>% formatStyle(names(df)[",i,"], backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks[,",i,"], 
clrs[,",i,"]))") ), collapse = " " ))))
```

I don't understand how to modify the clrs line and the rgb function in paste0 to get the colors that I want.  I have tinkered around with both of these chunks, but can not figure out how it works.  Can someone explain to me how I can exactly specify a color using the above code.  If I wanted to get the color blue or green or fade from one color to another, how would I go about doing that?

I am very stuck.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: What colours do you want? Please provide an expected output. `brks` defines the intervals for the colours based on the quantiles and `crls` generates the desired red by varying the G and B component in `rgb(255, G, B)`

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how I would manipulate the code above if I wanted to have white to green colors instead of white to red.  Or how could I modify this above to go from blue to red like some kind of heat map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `eval` is used to evaluate a name, a call or other... In this case it is a name. I propose a simpler code which I can explain each part, it will be your part to adapt it :

```
library(DT)

# the dataset
df <- cbind.data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10))

# the color wanted
sample_color <- data.frame(col1 = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.6),
                           col2 = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.3))

datatable(df) %>%
    formatStyle('1', color = eval(call(name = "rgb",
                                       matrix(sample_color$col1, ncol = 3))))
```

We need to use `matrix` because of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072288/passing-a-vector-to-rbg-in-r). The `eval` and `call` are only base R that you will probably better understand if you directly goes to their presentation pages : [eval](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/eval), [call](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/call).

**EDIT 1 Change the backgroung color of a datatable cell**

```
datatable(df) %>%
    formatStyle('1', color = eval(call(name = "rgb",
                                       matrix(sample_color$col1, ncol = 3))),
                backgroundColor = eval(call(name = "rgb",
                                             matrix(sample_color$col1, ncol = 3))))
```

Look at the package vignette of [DT](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/DT.pdf) to better understand how it works. There is a section formatCurrency which is suited for you.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you!   However, I'm looking to find ways to have the entire cell as a color instead of the text/number.